Accessing and live streaming camera from one phone to other with react native and node.js
How to access camera of child's phone from guardian phone using react native at frontend but Kotlin and java will also work. using Node.js at backend. You may also suggest me APIs or services or any other services that are useful.
I am new to react native.
